# Any way to share free/busy data only from a MobileMe calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, sharing, outlook, calendar, mobileme

I use several mobileme calendars, which I share fully with various colleagues. Some are mine, and some are calendars which others have shared with me. I access them through Outlook 2007 on my laptop (PC) and through my iPhone.

I would like to allow someone to access only my free/busy data, but across all of the multiple calendars. I know how to do this from the default Outlook calendar, but that is empty since I only use the multiple MobileMe ones.

I was thinking I could find a way to copy ALL info to the default outlook calendar and then share that either - but there would be a gap when my PC is switched off unless it is cloud-based in some way - eg google calendar, which allows free/busy sharing? Or if there is an app designed to fill this gap I would love to know about it.